# Auto Reply set up on Google Messenger - How to set so doesn't reply every time same person replies

Tags: google-messages

I have linked our Google Messenger to auto-reply via email as we are a doctor's office and the messenger is not monitored for canceled appointments.  The problem is we ask people to reply "Y" to confirm their appointments - sometimes there is additional messaging back and forth if we are in the office.  The auto-reply runs every time someone texts (a conversation).

Is there a way to have the auto-reply only send 1x to the same number if having a texting conversation instead of every time a response in the same conversation is sent without blocking the number because that defeats the point of auto-reply?

Comment: Google Messenger (Android Messages) doesn't seem to have an auto-reply feature. How did you set up the auto-reply?

Comment: I found this link and followed the instructions: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67645/how-do-i-auto-reply-to-text-messages-received-through-google-voice